# Can I use the mechanism powershell uses for displaying certain columns?

Tags: powershell

When you run `Get-Process` it returns:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    299      20     6148       1152      17.30  15980   1 ALMon
    336      14     8708       2700      14.13   5244   0 ALsvc
    408      24    22652      21644       8.97  16108   1 ApplicationFrameHost
...
```

- How does Powershell know which columns should be displayed and what should be their names?
- Can I use that mechanism when defining my custom objects?

Comment: https://poshoholic.com/2008/07/05/essential-powershell-define-default-properties-for-custom-objects/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Format.ps1xml files in PowerShell define the default display of objects in the PowerShell console. You can create your own Format.ps1xml files to change the display of objects or to define default displays for new object types that you create in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6).

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6#creating-new-formatps1xml-files) how you would extend that. The content is too much to post in the answer, but you can always find this information by searching for something like: `Powershell default formatting xml`